# Jekyll site not displaying correctly (wrong formatting) on Github pages

Tags: github, jekyll

Hey I am trying to set up Jekyll on Github pages. I have followed this guide exactly: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must replace the default `url` value in the config file. replace example.com and leave `baseurl` empty :

```
url: https://kekearif.github.io
baseurl: ""
```